# C# inheritance issue to do with collections

Tags: c#

In my application I access a number of companies of different types, say TypeA, TypeB and TypeC. So I have a company class and inherited from Company is TypeA, TypeB, TypeC.

So I have a view where the user wants to do a search on TypeA. The search fields include fields in Company and fields in TypeA.
However if I have a collection of TypeA, say IEnumberable, how do I filter the fields in the Company class before I filter them in the TypeA class?

EDIT

So this is my pseudo code

```
public abstract class Company
{
      public string Property1 { get; set; }
      public string Property2 { get; set; }

}

public class TypeA : Company
{
      public string Property3 {get; set; }
}

public class TypeB : Company
{
      public string Property4 {get; set; }
}

public abstract class SearchCompany
{
      protected SearchCompany(string searchpProperty1, string searchProperty2)
      {
           // assign property code elided
      }

      public string SearchProperty1 { get; set; }
      public string SearchProperty2 { get; set; }

}

public class SearchTypeA : SearchCompany
{
      public SearchTypeA (string searchpProperty1, string searchProperty2, string searchProperty3)
           : base (searchpProperty1, searchProperty2)
      {
          // assign property code elided
          this.TypeAList = CacheObjects.TypeAList;
          this.TypeAList = // this.TypeAList filtered by searchProperty3 depending on the wildcard
      }

      public string SearchProperty3 { get; set; }
      public IList<TypeA> TypeAList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to filter on properties 1 and 2 as well.

Comment: This is not very clear. Can you post pseudo code that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need to do one before the other?

Comment: Not sure of answer, but for others i think what he wants to do is find a way to filter a collection based upon fields in his base class before applying a filter to his inherited classes

Comment: Is this a LINQ question?

Comment: @Sayse - Which is a bit strange, as the fields should be available to the inheriting classes.

Comment: Sayse and James are right, I will post some code

Comment: @Oded yes, but I do not want to repeat code that can be done in the base class. I will have to put in the same code for all 3 derived classes

Comment: I don't follow - why would you have _filtering_ code in any of these classes? It would be external.

Comment: @Oded - I think its more that he wants to make sure his base fields are always filtered upon first

Comment: @Sayse - Which doesn't make much sense. What would the benefit of that be?

Comment: Ok Ok guys, you can see my code now. Maybe there is a better way of writing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`'s `OfType<T>()` method to pre-filter the list of `Company` objects, and produce `IEnumerable<TypeA>`, like this:

```
IEnumerable<TypeA> typeA = allCompanies.OfType<TypeA>();
```

You can use properties of `TypeA` in subsequent LINQ filters - the code below will work even if `Property1` is available only on `TypeA` and not on the `Company`:

```
var filteredTypeA = typeA.Where(c => c.Property1 = "xyz").ToList();
```